# How to query all data in a table that contains a foreign key from other table that contains multiple foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are my tables: 
[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ6dp.png) 
 
What I want to happen here is to formulate a query that retrieves all data from tblCurrentTransaction.

My query:

```
SELECT room_name, duration_name, price, final_price, check_in, check_out
FROM tblCurrentTransaction,
     tblRoomRates,
     tblRooms,
     tblDuration
WHERE tblRoomRates.room_id = tblRooms.id
  AND tblRoomRates.duration_id = tblDuration.id
```

Output:

[image: OUTPUT]

What happen is that it prints everything that is in the other tables.

 What I wanted it to do is to just print the data in tblCurrentTransaction

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Aren't you missing some join conditions? Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it:

```
SELECT room_name, duration_name, price, final_price, check_in, check_out
FROM tblCurrentTransaction,
     tblRoomRates,
     tblRooms,
     tblDuration
WHERE tblRoomRates.room_id = tblRooms.id
  AND tblRoomRates.duration_id = tblDuration.id
  AND tblCurrentTransaction.room_rate_id = tblRoomRates.id;
```